# How to connect Document Conversion Service with Watson Retrieval and Ranking

Tags: json, ibm-watson, watson, ranking-functions

I have 100 pdf documents. I have used Watson document conversion service  to convert pdf documents into JSON Answer Units. Now I need to train these documents.

I have written python code which needs JSON Answer Units and Document Relevency Score as input to Watson R and R.  How to refer JSON Answer Units through python code or How to download JSON Answer Units from Document Conversion Service through Python API

Answer (score 0):

I think you can see [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/examples/document_conversion_integration.v1.js) example from IBM Developers (Node SDK).
This [line](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/examples/document_conversion_integration.v1.js#L56) show one example for refer JSON Answer units.

The programming language is other but you can use the same logic to do what you want, the Document Conversion integration example shows how to convert a document into Answer Units by using the Document Conversion Service and upload it to the Retrieve and Rank Service to make the Answer Units searchable.

> 1. Create a solr cluster, upload the solr configuration and create a collection
>
>    1.1 In the files retrieve_and_ran_lifecycle.v1.js  and retrieve_and_rank_solr.v1.js you will find example functions
>          on how to perform these steps.
>
>    1.2 IMPORTANT: When uploading the solr configuration, use the [answer_unit_config.zip] from the resources folder,
>      which includes a schema.xml that defines the fields that will be indexed.
> 2. Edit the file document_conversion_integration.v1.js and enter the following:
>
>    2.1 service credentials for the Document Conversion and the Retrieve and Rank services (each service instance has a different set of credentials)
>
>    2.2 clusterId (obtained when creating the cluster)
>
>    2.3 collectionName and inputDocument if you are using a different value from the default
> 3. Run the following command:

```
node document_conversion_integration.v1.js
```